# Rendering Error for Ajax Upvoting System

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using the gem "acts_as_votable" in my Rails application so that Users can vote on Posts.

I'm adding Ajax functionality so that the entire page doesn't have to refresh when a user upvotes a post. This is what I have:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'} 

  resources :posts do 
    member do
      put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
    end
  end

  # Define Root URL
  root 'pages#index'

  # Define Routes for Pages
  get '/home' => 'pages#home'
  get '/explore' => 'pages#explore'
  get '/privacy' => 'pages#privacy'
  get '/:id' => 'pages#profile'

end
```

pages_controller.rb

```
  def explore
    @posts = Post.where('created_at >= :one_days_ago', one_days_ago: Time.now - 16.hours)
  end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    @posts = Post.allow
    end

    def new 
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.user_id = current_user.id
        respond_to do |f|
            if (@post.save) 
                f.html { redirect_to :back, :flash => { :notice => "Posted" } }
            else
                f.html { redirect_to :back, :flash => { :alert => "Error" } }
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        if current_user == @post.user
            @post.destroy
        end
            redirect_to :back, alert: 'Deleted.'
    end



    def upvote
        @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
      @posts.upvote_by current_user
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to :back }
            format.js 
        end
    end

    def downvote
        @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
      @posts.downvote_by current_user
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to :back }
            format.js 
        end
    end



    private
    def post_params # allows certain data to be passed via form.
        params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :content)
    end

end
```

explore.html.erb

```
<% if @posts.each do |p| %>
<div class="panel-body">
  <p class="post-content"><%= auto_link(p.content, :html => { :target => '_blank' }) %></p>

  <%= render :partial => 'vote', :class => "vote", :locals => { p: @posts } %>

</div>
<% end %>
```

_vote.html.erb

```
<div id="vote_<%= p.id %>" class="vote">
  <%= link_to 'Vote Up', like_post_path(p), :class => "upvote", :method => :put, :remote => true %>
  <span><%= p.score %></span>  <!--show the current vote-->
  <%= link_to 'Vote Down', dislike_post_path(p), :class => "downvote", :method => :put, :remote => true %>
</div>
```

upvote.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vote_<%= p.id %>').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => '/pages/vote' %>");
});
```

When I go to run the project I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#explore

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/pages/_vote.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `id' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f6715d018e8>

Did you mean?  ids

<div id="vote_<%= p.id %>" class="vote">
```

The issue arises from trying to render _votes.html.erb.

Where am I going wrong here? I've been stuck on this for a while and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing entire collection to partial

```
  <% if @posts.each do |p| %>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p class="post-content"><%= auto_link(p.content, :html => { :target =>     '_blank' }) %></p>

    <%= render :partial => 'vote', :class => "vote", :locals => { p: @posts } %>

  </div>
  <% end %>
```

In line `<%= render :partial => 'vote', :class => "vote", :locals => { p: @posts } %>` replace `@posts` with `p`